# SQL: Update fields based on another fields information

Tags: oracle, sql-update

I am trying to automate an UPDATE query based off one columns data and apply that same field to another.

See screenshot:

[image]

In this, what I am trying to do is update PCODE from a value of 0 to that of the value shown in SI_PCODE. This would need to be updated by the unique variable of the SALES_QUOTE_ID. I currently do this manually with excel using

```
update sales_quote_contact set pcode= where sales_quote_id=;
```

but want to run this automatically through a batch job I have.

Comment: `update sales_quote_contact set pcode = si_pcode where pcode = 0`? But why are duplicating that information?

Comment: There are two parts of our database, one that keeps track of Subscriber information and one that keeps track of quote information. This is a bug currently with our dev but is a low priority for then right now.

Comment: Here is my current query if that helps understand it better

>
select sq.subscriber_id, sq.sales_quote_id, sqc.pcode, sci.subscriber_id AS AM_SI, sci.pcode AS SI_PCODE from sales_quote sq
join sales_quote_contact sqc on sqc.sales_quote_id=sq.sales_quote_id
join sub_contact_info sci on sci.subscriber_id=sq.subscriber_id
where sq.sales_quote_id in ()
order by sq.sales_quote_id asc;